# Delete to the beginning of the next line in vim?

Tags: vim

Given text like this:

```
This is line one.
This is line two.
```

I would like to change it to this:

```
This is line one. This is line two.
```

If my cursor is at the end of line one, how is this done with vim, regardless of what line two starts with? Also, are there different ways to do it with/without whitespace?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put your cursor anywhere on line 1, then type `J`.

Comment: And if you don't need to insert or remove any spaces when joining lines, use `gJ`.

Comment: This seems to preserve some whitespace, is there a way to do it without any whitespace?

Comment: I'll take Vim for $200, Alex.